# Unable to upload video on VZAAR using .NET API v2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, api, video-upload, vzaar-api

We have `VZAAR` subscription to upload/view videos. `VZAAR` recently changed their APIs that connect with **AWS S3**. Their .NET API does not work, we are facing following error:

Web page keeps loading when we call `"HttpSendAsync"` method of `"Client.cs"` class.

The last piece of code that executes is:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await this.httpClient.SendAsync (msg);
```

**Complete code** is provided below.

`VZAAR's` web interface provides some test methods online that are working fine and `VZAAR` support recommends to use PHP which we don't know.

```
internal async virtual Task<string> HttpSendAsync(HttpRequestMessage msg) {

            if (CfgUrlAuth == true) {

                Dictionary<string, string> query = new Dictionary<string, string> ();
                query.Add ("client_id", client_id);
                query.Add ("auth_token", auth_token);

                Uri uri = BuildQuery (msg.RequestUri, query);
                msg.RequestUri = uri;

            } else {

                msg.Headers.Add ("X-Client-Id", client_id);
                msg.Headers.Add ("X-Auth-Token", auth_token);

            }

            #if DEBUG 
            Debug.WriteLine ("\n\nRequest Method");
            Debug.WriteLine (msg.Method.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine ("Request Uri");
            Debug.WriteLine (msg.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);
            Debug.WriteLine ("Request Headers");
            Debug.WriteLine (msg.Headers.ToString().Trim());

            if (msg.Content != null) {
                Debug.WriteLine ("Request Content");
                string debug_content = await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
                Debug.WriteLine (debug_content);
            }
            #endif

            HttpResponseMessage response = await this.httpClient.SendAsync (msg);

            ValidateHttpResponse (response);

            httpHeaders = response.Headers;

            var bodyResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

            return bodyResponse;
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  It seems to be missing from the question?

Comment: HttpResponseMessage response = await this.httpClient.SendAsync (msg); This line of code does not return any results. The page keeps loading.

Comment: That line of code is already present in your question and isn't an error.

Comment: this.httpClient.SendAsync (msg); does not return any result.